# Need to call a javascript to the markup code of a gridview data binding

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I am having a gridview and needs to bind a `list<class object>`, say `List<Class_A>` to it
consider

```
  Class_A.status = 0 or 1 (it always has any of these two values)
```

I wrote a JavaScript as

```
  function Item_Type(status) {
     if (status== 0)
        var type="Inventory Item";
     else
        var type = "Non-Inventory Item";
     return type;
  }
```

My gridview has a column as `Item Type`

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Item Type" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                 HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="Label41" runat="server" Text='<%# 'Eval(status)'%>'> 
     </asp:Label>--%>
     </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

To solve my issue I need to call the js `Item_Type(status)`, and evaluate it to the gridspace corresponding to `Eval(status)`. How can I?

Note: To explain my question, `Eval(status)` will display only 0 or 1 as output, but instead I need `Inventory Item` or `Non_Inventory Item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below should work.

```
Text='<%# Eval("status").ToString()=="0"?"Inventory Item":"Non-Inventory Item" %>'
```

Comment: yes.thanku . your code works pretty fine, and my problem is solved